# Android Studio: Change Application Theme Rendering Problems

Tags: android

Sorry for my stupidy. I know it's simple but I'm a beginner. I've looked around and I couldn't find the answer.

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

I'm trying to change the Application Theme, but I am always getting that error:

> **Rendering Problems**
>
> > Missing Styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
> >
> > > Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout or fix the theme style references.
> > >
> > > **Note: One or more layout are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.**
> > >
> > > **Exception Details:**
> > >
> > > > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library

Comment: Have you searched for solutions online. You would find similar questions asked already. like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: I noticed that solution. I tried extening Activity instead but it doesn't find class named Activity.

Comment: Extend AppCompatActivity instead

Comment: I've managed to fix it by creating a new project and making the Activity an Empty Activity instead of other kind of activity I've used.
Thank you!